# OpenFileDialog causes WPF app to crash

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog, savefiledialog, filedialog

In my `WPF` Application I used `OpenFileDialog` to select an image and load it to app, this works fine as expected.

But if I run same app from a flash drive, image loades after that `UI` freezes, any clicks on `UI` makes app to crash.

I have admin `manifest` to app also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF App File access error on flash drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655939/wpf-app-file-access-error-on-flash-drive)

Comment: Please avoid double posting so those with legitimate questions have a chance to be helped.

Comment: Thanks. I removed that old post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here In this case `OpenFileDialog` will cause the app to hang and crash.

So moved `OpenFileDialog` to a new thread. And everything works fine.

Comment: This thread issue also happens in Windows Forms: your app can crash while debugging a click event handler, which calls a Save or Open Dialog, and Visual Studio fires in output window: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll`

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a good explanation but I solved this problem setting the InitialDirectory with a valid local path (e.g., Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar to this before when running from a network drive. If the application is not being loaded from a completely trusted source, you can get a SecurityException.

In any case, try adding a try/catch block around the code that fails to see if you are getting an exception.

Comment: Here I am not getting security exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem occurs (crash) not only in WPF, but for WinForms.
It is hard to say what is the source of the problem, but still it appears that Microsoft dll related to OpenFileDialog has bugs (for me, it was CmnDlg32.dll)

The only way I could call ShowDialog() function was to wrap it in the event and call with the help of

```
this.BeginInvoke(
        new Action<YourObject, EventArgs>(YourObject_FileDialogOpened), new object[] 
                                                        { YourObjectInstance, e });
```

where "this" is a Control (for example, Form).

BeginInvoke(...) grants that you call will be process in a proper way.

Problem will not appear if you use call of the OpenFileDialog under button click event or any other similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

How Winform crash when using OpenFileDialog

```
using(var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
   ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg)|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg";
   if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) // <-- reason of crashing
   {
     PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
   }
}
```

How to fix the issue

```
using(var ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
   ofd.Filter = "Image Files (*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg)|*.png;*.bmp;*.jpg";
   DialogResult Action = a.ShowDialog();
   if(Action == DialogResult.OK) // <-- To fix
   {
     PictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(ofd.FileName);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                using (SaveFileDialog fd = new SaveFileDialog())
                {
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arScene, Formatting.Indented);

                    var bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json); // or any byte array data

                    fd.Filter = "JSon files (*.json)|*.json|All files (*.*)|*.*|ARScene (*.ARScene)|*.ARScene";
                    fd.Title = "Save an ARScene File";
                    fd.AutoUpgradeEnabled = true;
                    fd.DefaultExt = "ARScene";
                    fd.OverwritePrompt = false;
                    fd.RestoreDirectory = true;
                    fd.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;
                    fd.CreatePrompt = false;

                    if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        if (fd.FileName != "")
                        {
                            FileStream fs = (FileStream)fd.OpenFile();
                            if (fs != null)
                            {
                                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                                fs.Close();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    fd.Dispose(); // not needed, but save;-)
                }
}));
```