# VB.NET 2015 - OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() crashes the application

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

So, due to other issues I've been forced to update to VB.NET **2015** from VB.NET **2010**.

In VB.NET **2010** I was able to do something as simple as OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() all the time, but here in VB.NET **2015** I can't do this because the application running in Visual Basic debug test will just close when I run the call...

**NOTE**: When I run the program outside Visual Basic from the ".../bin/debug" directory. The call to open a OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() works just fine...

I don't get it...

Please Help.

EDIT: My Grammar

Comment: That's obviously not normal. I'd advice upgrading to VS 2019 if you can but, if your company is standardised on VS 2015 or the like then you're stuck with it. I'd suggest testing similar code in a different project and, if possible, the same project on a different machine. Something is likely corrupt either in that project or on that machine. You may need to repair/reinstall VS to fix a corrupt file.

Comment: Since I'm part of IT, I have access to my companies remote share server, so I could just downgrade back to VS 2010 since to be honest I only installed it to kill time at work.

Before I do it though, I will test the same code on my laptop which has VB.NET 2010.
If that works then I'll downgrade on my work PC.

My work does not yet have a VS 2019 license, something about management saying "If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Besides that's more money for features we don't need yet."
Doesn't really bother me though, VS 2010 is still great in many ways.

Anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: [Call to OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog hangs or freezes](https://wishmesh.com/2011/06/call-to-openfiledialog-or-savefiledialog-hangs-or-freezes/) suggests that setting `OpenFileDialog1.ShowHelp = True` will make it work, while [OpenFileDialog causes WPF app to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13656078/1115360) has some more suggestions.

Comment: `NOTICE: Have not found/tried to find a solution - This questions will be left untouched by me. If anything happens to this question, I wish you luck in your search for a fix. My fix was to uninstall Visual Studio 2015, and fresh install Visual Studio 2010. (Not a real fix, but it worked)`